# tool / utility / resource for checking compatibility of javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have a application completely written for IE 6 and below. No wonder it doesnt work in any other browsers. But my objective here is to make it work in all the latest browsers. Is there any specific tool or utility or resource that verifies / goes through my javascript files and reports me the issues in it and suggestions.

Any suggestion or direction in this regard is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: There's JSLint and the new, related JSHint, but with code like that you may get a **lot** of warnings ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a tool would be extremely difficult to create given the large number of quirks and changes to Javascript over different versions. I do not know of any such tool but here are some suggestions:

- Have multiple versions of browsers installed on your computer including older versions as well, virtualize if necessary
- Tools such as IETab for Chrome/Firefox can help with managing too many windows
- Unit testing

I would also consider not writing your own cross-browser compatible Javascript. It requires a significant research investment and time commitment. Instead you could use an already cross-browser compatible Javascript library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) which does it all for you. I highly suggest going this route as it could take you hours to self-code even the most basic cross-browser compatible Javascript which is doable in less than a minute with libraries such as jQuery.